# Showing optional double number on a label

Tags: swift, label, double, option-type, unwrap

I'm trying to show a double number on a label. But it shows as an optional. I can't unwrap it using "!" because some of the data is nil.

How can I make the "Optional(...)" text not show up?

This is how it looks:

```
let row = elementArray[indexPath.row]
mPoint.text = String(row.meltPoint) //Optional(2070.0)
```

Comment: What do you want to happen if the data is nil?

Comment: Show "N/A" instead of "nil"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `if let` to unwrap optional values:

```
let row = elementArray[indexPath.row]
if let myNumber = row.meltPoint {
    mPoint.text = "\(myNumber)"
} else {
     mPoint.text = "N/A"
}
```

Comment: in the else just pass your custom string to it I'm updating the answer so you can see

Comment: Thank you very much